# Vue Search Bar to Filter Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am trying to filter a v-for loop list of stores. The Vue code I have works if filtering by `"store"`, but I'm struggling to find out how to have the search filter work with nested json like `"section_name"` and even deeper `"items"`.

examples:
search "milk" -> `Store A dairy section only (match daily/almond milk in item)`
search "fruit" -> `Store B fruit section only (match fruit sectio_name)`
search "green" -> `Store A veggie section only (match green beans item)`

```
<script setup>
import { computed, reactive, ref } from "vue";

const stores = reactive([]);
const mySearch = ref("");

fetch("http://localhost:8081/sample.json")
  .then((res) => res.json())  
  .then((data) => {
    data.forEach(el => {
      stores.push(el)
    });
  })

const filterStores = computed(() => {
   return stores.filter((store) => {
      return store.store.toLowerCase().indexOf(mySearch.value.toLowerCase()) != -1
   });
})

</script>


<template>
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row header">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-0 p-4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="select store" class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="mySearch"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <div v-for="(store, index) in filterStores" :key="index">
              <li>{{ store.store }}</li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
```

```
sample.json file
[
    {
        "store": "Store A",
        "data": [
            {
                "section_name": "veggies",
                "section_num": "301",
                "items": [
                    "carrots",
                    "green beans"
                ]
            },
            {
                "section_name": "dairy",
                "section_num": "302",
                "items": [
                    "dairy milk",
                    "almond milk"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "store": "Store B",
        "data": [
            {
                "section_name": "fruit",
                "section_num": "336",
                "items": [
                    "apples",
                    "oranges"
                ]
            },
            {
                "section_name": "bread",
                "items": [
                    "wheat bread"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Once starting to try to match nested terms, you may want to look at handing off search to a dedicated index like elasticsearch, rather than creating your own complex filtering while looping

Comment: The full data is 5kb json file  (256 lines) that changes once a year. I'm not familiar with elasticsearch, would it be a bit overkill for this use case?

Comment: Even for that size of data, you will still need to create a lot of regex / filtering so that someone typing `apple` still gets the `apples` to match. So it depends how 'good' the search ability needs to be but most humans will probably appreciate search predicatbility they are more used to.
When I was learning to use elastic with a node app this article got me there really quickly https://www.markpenovich.com/posts/how-to-search-a-postgres-database-with-node-elasticsearch-and-sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out specifically what output you want from the function, so let's tackle this from the simplest, and get more complex from there, like so:

1. List the store object if any of its sections contain a match
2. List a copy of the store object containing only the relevant sections

Also, we'll use [includes() from the String Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to do the actual matching. You can replace the comparison method with a regex match or some other solution, but your current direct comparison won't find 'milk' out of 'almond milk' because `'milk' !== 'almond milk'` but `'almond milk'.includes('milk')`.

toLowerCase() will be left out for brevity, because you're already making use of it.

Finally, `{}` and `return` will be left out since each function is returning the result of a one-liner.

#### Stores containing matches

So we want to *return each* `store` with *at least one* `data` with an `items` array containing *at least one* item that includes TERM.

Since we only need to find *at least one* instance of a match for this case, we'll filter on the store, then use [find() from the Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). find takes a function rather than a value, and returns undefined (a falsy value), rather than -1, if nothing is found.

```
const filtered = computed(
  () => stores.filter( //return each store with
    store => store.data.find( //a data item that contains at least one
      d => d.items.find( //items array that contains at least one
        item => item.includes(TERM) //item that includes TERM
      )
    )
  )
)
```

#### Sections containing matches

Based on your examples, it looks like you only want to return the matching sections, rather than the matching stores. For that, we'll use [map() from the Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to replace the results from our filtered list with an object where the `data` array contains only the relevant stores.

We'll [destructure the parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) of our mapping function so that we can more easily structure our returned object.

```
const sections = computed(
  () => filtered.value.map(
    ({ store, data }) => ({ 
      store, data: data.filter(
        d => d.items.find(
          item => item.includes(TERM)
        )
      )
    })
  )
)
```

You can modify the output of the map function to match the exact shape of the data you want to return.